# Move an image from one tab to another

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a football worksheet and I'm not able to pass an image from one tab to another.

Inside the worksheet I have tabs that correspond to the championship rounds, and inside these tabs I wanted to put the name of a team and the badge of that team next to it.
[Tab "Round 38" - I want to put the badge in the B column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSajT.png)

That's why I created another tab with just the name of the teams and the shield right next to it.
[This tab is called "Escudos"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBP1n.png)

What I want to do is, when I put the team name in column C, the shield referring to the team appears in column B.
I tried using OFFSET and VLOOKUP, but I couldn't make it work, most likely because I'm still a layman in excel.

Comment: VLOOKUP doesn't return shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in B4 (I estimate that this is the first cell based on your picture, if not change B4 and C4 based on your first row):

```
=INDEX(Escudos!C:C,MATCH(C4,Escudos!B:B,0))
```

Or just with this formula in B4 you can have the full column filled (remember to delete everything below it in B column):

```
=byrow(C4:C,lambda(each,if(each="","",INDEX(Escudos!C:C,MATCH(each,Escudos!B:B,0)))))
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much!
I used the first formula you gave, I just changed the "," to ";". I'm using Google Sheets.

Comment: Me too, it just depends on your language configuration ;)